# Altering Hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash

```
original_hash = {"10"=>3, "15"=>2, "20"=>1}
```

I want to make a new hash, call it `results_hash`, where the keys of `original_hash` will be appended `'$'` sign and the new values to the keys will be (key * value) of the `original_hash`. The generated `results_hash` should be:

```
results_hash = {"$10"=>30, "$15"=>30, "$20"=>20}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
original_hash = {"10"=>3, "15"=>2, "20"=>1}
results_hash = Hash[original_hash.map { |k,v| ['$'+k,k.to_i*v] }]
p results_hash # => {"$10"=>30, "$15"=>30, "$20"=>20}

original_hash = {"10"=>3, "15"=>2, "20"=>1}
results_hash = original_hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h['$'+k]=k.to_i*v }
p results_hash # => {"$10"=>30, "$15"=>30, "$20"=>20}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
resulted_hash = {}

original_hash.each do |key, val|
 resulted_hash["$" + k] = v*k.to_i
end
```

Comment: `each_with_object` is better.. :)

Comment: Read the question carefully.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - Thanks. went through the docs. will keep it in mind going forward.